# Seasonal raster means with calc function in R

Tags: r, raster

I looking for a way to aggregate several raster by seasonal index in R. I've tried to use stackApply function but the resulting layers has NA values in all layers. Also, I've tried with zApply but the resulting layer has layers unsort and they don't match with the layer's names. Calc is slower but safer in processing.

Calc function has the next error. Calc works for monthly and yearly means but not for seasonal

```
r_name<-str_sub(r_files,-12,-5);r_name

groups <- function(x) {
  d <- as.POSIXlt(idx)
  ans <- character(length(x))
  ans[d$mon %in% c(11,0,1)] <- "DJF"
  ans[d$mon %in%  2:4] <- "MAM"
  ans[d$mon %in%  5:7] <- "JJA"
  ans[d$mon %in% 8:10] <- "SON"
  ans
}

idx<-as.Date(r_name, format = "%Y%m%d")

NDVI<-stack(r_files)

rstack <- setZ(NDVI,idx)
NDVI_seasonal_hist <- calc(rstack,fun=function(x) { by(x, format(groups(format(idx,"%Y%m"))), mean, na.rm = T)})
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example